# Share images and text on whatsapp on Android / iOS through Web app using angular or java

Tags: javascript, angular, whatsapp

I have problem in sharing images and text on whatsapp .  I used javaScript webShare API but it doesnot works with IOS "When I am sharing Images with text" it works only when i share only images or only text . So  I want alternative solution or alternative way using java or angular js.If you have any idea give some solution

I tried using Web share API of JS . It is not working with IOS. It is working with Android. I wanted it to work for both .

Comment: Are you using the (ancient) 1.x AngularJS, or a newer Angular? Please use only the relevant tag.

Comment: @jorn I am using angular12